# Pascal : fatal syntax error

Tags: pascal

Trying to execute catalan numbers in Pascal but getting fatal syntax error.

Error is :

```
Fatal: Syntax error, ";" expected but "identifier B" found 
Error: /usr/bin/ppcx64 returned an error exitcode
```

Here is ref code

```
program main;

var
 i,buf: integer;

function catalan(num: integer): integer;
var
 sample, returnval : integer;

 function bincoeff(n: integer): integer;
  var
    a,b,retval,numr,denom1,denom2: integer;
    bc : integer;

  function fact(x: integer): integer;
  begin
  // fact exec
  if x=0 then
   fact :=1
  else
   fact := x* fact(x-1);
  end;
 begin
 //bincoeff exec
 a := 2*n
 b := n
 if a==b then
  retval :=1
 else if b>a
  retval :=0
 else
 numr := fact(a)
 denom1 := fact(b)
 denom2 := fact(a-b)
 bc := numr /(denom1*denom2)

 retval := bc 
 end;
begin
// catalan exec
sample :=bincoeff(num)
returnval := (sample/(num+1))
end;


begin

  for i :=0 to 9 do
  begin
   buf := catalan(i)
   writeln(buf)
  end;

end.
```

Comment: Apart from the other comments and the answer, `==` is not a valid operator in Pascal. Comparison is done with `=`. And you must indeed use `;` as separators between statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with

```
a := 2*n
```

till the end of the program you systematically don't use ';'. A fact that, by the way, is signaled pretty clearly by the compiler.

In this context it might be interesting to visit [the FreePascal wiki on the topic of the semicolon](http://wiki.freepascal.org/;) which points out an important difference between C and Pascal's usage of the semicolon (separator vs terminator). A must-read.

Comment: Thank you! Helpful suggestion!

Comment: Did you know that the numbers that fpc prints before the error message that you reproduced (in this case (27,2) are actually the **line** and **column** where it encountered a problem?

Comment: Yes! Now I corrected all syntax issues. But arguments are not passing as expected. I will update my code! Thank You!

Comment: If you encounter further, logic-type errors, I would suggest to open a new question. This one has served its purpose and mixing two levels of problems in one question is frowned upon on SO. However, before you ask a question that pertains to a logic problem, be sure to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thank You! I will open a new question! This problem has been resolved!